# Can't display circle drawn on google map API

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework, draw

I'm working on a project using Angular / Ionic,
I've searched in the docs and I started using the predefined

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/undefined?origin=...&q=...&destination=...&center=...&zoom=...&key=..." allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Now that I have the map, I'd like to draw circles on this map, but I've tried many things and failed.

**here's my code:**

```
location: any;
cityCircle: any;
map: any;
marker: any;

ngOnInit() {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));
    this.location = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=" + this.navParams.get('Loca') + "&zoom=12&key=KEYCODE";
    console.log(this.navParams.get('Lat'), this.navParams.get('Long'), this.navParams.get('Radius'));
    var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: this.map,
        center: {
            lat: this.navParams.get('Lat'),
            lng: this.navParams.get('Long')
        },
        radius: this.navParams.get('Radius') * 10000
    });
```

Comment: Can you post the link to the docs you refer to? All the examples of google maps that I've seen, load the libraries with <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key= ...>. Also, do you have a div with id == "map" in your html?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start?hl=fr I started using this, but it seems that the <iframe> does not support drawing on it, I replaced it with <div id="map"></map> like most doc said, worked perfectly

Comment: ok. That's ok for embed a map, but you can not use it for your purposes. You need to use the [JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map#premiers_pas), and then you will be able to [draw shapes on the map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#circles)

Comment: ok, it's working, but will it on an android/ios device ?

Comment: Sure, just test the hello world example and draw some circles. By the way, it's important to add a style to the map (like it appears in the hello world example), #map{ height. 100%, width: 100% }. Also, you can use angular modules like [angular-google-maps](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/), which ease many tasks.